# Sort dictionary items using a key while looping

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
sequence = {
   'group4': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 4, 'warmup_time': 300, 'shutdown_order': 6, 'servers': ['group4_1', 'group4_2']},
   'group1': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 1, 'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 10, 'servers': ['group1_1', 'group1_2', 'group1_3']}, 
   'group3': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 3, 'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 7, 'servers': ['group3_1', 'group3_2']},
   'group2': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 2, 'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 8, 'servers': ['group2_1', 'group2_2']}
}
```

I wanted to create a loop that will go through this list using a value in the `sequence` dictionary (e.g. `sequence['group4']['startup_order']`). How do I do this using `sorted()`?

I tried using this:

```
for k, v in sorted(sequence.items(), key=sequence[k]['startup_order']):
  print(k, v)
```

but it's throwing an error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment`

Comment: A key function has to be a _function_. This is explained pretty nicely, with examples, in the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) in the official docs.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 4):

For [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) try using a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) for the key like:

#### Code:

```
for k, v in sorted(sequence.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['startup_order']):
    print(k, v)
```

#### Test Code:

```
sequence = {
    'group4': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 4,
               'warmup_time': 300, 'shutdown_order': 6,
               'servers': ['group4_1', 'group4_2']},
    'group1': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 1,
               'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 10,
               'servers': ['group1_1', 'group1_2', 'group1_3']},
    'group3': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 3,
               'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 7,
               'servers': ['group3_1', 'group3_2']},
    'group2': {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 2,
               'warmup_time': 900, 'shutdown_order': 8,
               'servers': ['group2_1', 'group2_2']}
}

for k, v in sorted(sequence.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['startup_order']):
    print(k, v)
```

#### Results:

```
('group1', {'servers': ['group1_1', 'group1_2', 'group1_3'], 'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 1, 'shutdown_order': 10, 'warmup_time': 900})
('group2', {'servers': ['group2_1', 'group2_2'], 'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 2, 'shutdown_order': 8, 'warmup_time': 900})
('group3', {'servers': ['group3_1', 'group3_2'], 'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 3, 'shutdown_order': 7, 'warmup_time': 900})
('group4', {'servers': ['group4_1', 'group4_2'], 'shutdown_grace': 300, 'startup_order': 4, 'shutdown_order': 6, 'warmup_time': 300})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do with `Sorted()` and then convert it into Ordered dict :

```
import collections

data=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(sequence.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]['shutdown_order']))
```

Now data is a dict, on which you can iterate like a normal dict :

```
for i,j in data.items():
   print(i,j)
```

output:

```
group4 {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'warmup_time': 300, 'startup_order': 4, 'servers': ['group4_1', 'group4_2'], 'shutdown_order': 6}
group2 {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'warmup_time': 900, 'startup_order': 2, 'servers': ['group2_1', 'group2_2'], 'shutdown_order': 8}
group1 {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'warmup_time': 900, 'startup_order': 1, 'servers': ['group1_1', 'group1_2', 'group1_3'], 'shutdown_order': 10}
group3 {'shutdown_grace': 300, 'warmup_time': 900, 'startup_order': 3, 'servers': ['group3_1', 'group3_2'], 'shutdown_order': 70}
```